# Error con trigger con IF y UPDATE en ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

ejecutando este disparador en ORACLE me surgió el siguiente error:

```
 Table,View Or Sequence reference 'OCEX_COMI.FECHA_ASIG_GT' not allowed in 
 this context.
```

Este es mi trigger:

```
 create or replace trigger ocex_comi_total
 before insert or update of id_gt,fecha_asig_gt on ocex_comi
 for each row
 begin
 if ((ocex_comi.fecha_asig_gt > to_date('2018-12-15','yyyy-mm-dd')) and 
     (ocex_comi.fecha_asig_gt < to_date('2019-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))) 
 then
    update ocex_comi cm set
    cm.PAGO_COM = (select uea.total_bono_especial from OCEX_UEA uea                   
                    join OCEX_GUIA_TRANSITO gt on uea.id_uea = gt.dest_id
                    where gt.cod_gt=cm.id_gt)
    where cm.id_gt = (select gt.cod_gt from ocex_guia_transito gt JOIN 
                      ocex_uea uea on uea.id_uea=gt.dest_id 
                            where gt.cod_gt=cm.id_gt);
else
    update ocex_comi cm set
    cm.PAGO_COM = (select uea.total_x_pnp from OCEX_UEA uea                   
                    join OCEX_GUIA_TRANSITO gt on uea.id_uea = gt.dest_id
                    where gt.cod_gt=cm.id_gt)
    where cm.id_gt = (select gt.cod_gt from ocex_guia_transito gt JOIN 
                      ocex_uea uea on uea.id_uea=gt.dest_id 
                            where gt.cod_gt=cm.id_gt);
end if;
end;
```

Bueno lo que intentaba hacer es que con este disparador la columnna "PAGO_COM" de la tabla "ocex_comi" se rellene automáticamente desde la tabla "ocex_uea" gracias a la columna "total_bono_especial" (si en caso la fecha del campo "fecha_asig_gt" esté comprendida entre 15-dec hasta 31-dec) y si no, que se rellene de la columna "total_x_pnp" (si la fecha de del campo "fecha_asig_gt no se encuentra entre  el 15-dec hasta el 31-dec). Alguna idea o ayuda con el error que me sale. Gracias.

Comment: prueba aplicándole una conversión de fecha así como haces aquí to_date('2018-12-15','yyyy-mm-dd'), quizá la comparación de fechas no tiene el mismo formato.

Comment: @JaphSxas te refieres a ponerlo así ((to_date(ocex_comi.fecha_asig_gt,'dd/mm/aa') > to_date('12/15/18','dd/mm/aa')). Porque si es así me sigue tirando el mismo error :(